# Magento: getting giftcard code and amount

Tags: php, magento

I'm having difficulty retrieving the giftcard code and amount used on an order. For example in `Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`, there is a piece of code that works with a Sales/Order model. i.e.

```
($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) is true in the PDF example
```

or

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderID); in another example
```

In the invoice PDF that gets printed, the total section shows the gift card that was used as well as  coupon code that was used. The coupon code can be obtained by `$order->getCouponCode()`.

How do I get the giftcard code and amount from `$order`? I've tried

```
$order->getGiftcertCode();
$order->getGiftcertAmount();
```

but these don't return anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a few ways to do this, but I haven't had to do it before so just from looking at the sales_flat_order table in the Magento database, I can see that there are a number of fields that you can use to reference different gift card amounts:

```
base_gift_cards_amount
gift_cards_amount
base_gift_cards_invoiced
gift_cards_invoiced
base_gift_cards_refunded
gift_cards_refunded
```

These can be accessed with the following calls:

```
$order->getBaseGiftCardsAmount();
$order->getGiftCardsAmount();
$order->getBaseGiftCardsInvoiced();
$order->getGiftCardsInvoiced();
$order->getBaseGiftCardsRefunded();
$order->getGiftCardsRefunded();
```

The one you want to use is probably `$order->getGiftCardsAmount()`

In order to get the gift card details, they are stored as a serialised array in the "gift_cards" column of the above table. So to get that array, call

```
$cards = unserialize($order->getGiftCards());
```

print_r $cards and you'll see something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
             [i] => 1
             [c] => {{Gift Card Code}}
             [a] => {{Gift Card Amount}}
             [ba] => {{Gift Card Base Amount}}
         )

)
```

so

```
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    echo "Code: " . $card['c'] . "\n";
    echo "Amount: " . $card['a'] . "\n";
}
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Genuis! Could point to me how I would have figured out what methods (those calls you listed) are available for the `$order` variable? I went through the Magento documentation available online, but I was having a hard time finding anything related.

Comment: Well it's quite straightforward actually, in Magento the function names for any data "getters" or "setters" are dynamic. They are camelCased from the name of the data, most often this is the column in the database. As an example, if the data in the database column is called `gift_cards_amount`, you can call `->getGiftCardsAmount()`, which is the same as `->getData("gift_cards_amount")`. This is why you won't find any documentation on a lot of `get` and `set` related functions.

Comment: That is really good to know. I installed a community version on localhost to examine the DB (not that giftcard stuff is there) for future reference! Thanks!